# NHibernate 2.2 how to setup list relationship

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate, sqlite

I don't work with NHibernate 2.2 usualy so I have few questions which I am unable to find good explanation.
I have 2 tables: Points and Files.

Declared as C# classes:

```
[Serializable]
    public class PPoint
    {
        public PPoint()
        {
        }

        public virtual int PPointID { get; set; }
        public virtual int Position { get; set; }
        public virtual int ImportID { get { if (ImportFile == null) return -1; else return ImportFile.ImportID; } }
        public virtual PPImportFile ImportFile { get; set; }

        public virtual int Name{ get; set; }
        //more properties
    }

[Serializable]
public class PPImportFile
{
    public PPImportFile()
    {
        Points = new List<PPoint>();
    }

    private static Repositories.PPointRepository ppr; 

    public virtual int ImportID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FileName{ get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<PPoint> Points { get; set; }

    public virtual int PointCount { get { return Points.Count; } }
}
```

My mappings are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="WebGPS.Data"
                   namespace="WebGPS.Data.Domain">

<id name="PPointID" column ="PPointID" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="-1">
    <generator class="assigned"></generator>
</id>
<property name="Position" />
<!--<property name="ImportID" />-->
<many-to-one name="ImportFile" column="ImportID" update="true" insert="true" not-null="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan"  />

    <property name="Name" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                       assembly="WebGPS.Data"
                       namespace="WebGPS.Data.Domain">

  <class name="PPImportFile" lazy="true">
    <id name="ImportID" column ="ImportID" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="-1">
        <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="FailoPav" />
    <property name="ImportoData" />
    <property name="ImportavoVart" />

    <list name="Points" table="PPoint" cascade="all" lazy="true">
      <key column="PPointID" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
      <index column="Position"/>
      <one-to-many class="PPoint"/>
    </list>
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code to insert new file with points:

```
PPImportFile file = new PPImportFile();

int newPointID = pp.GetNewPontID(); // Get next Point ID from repository
do
{
   PPoint pt = new PPoint();
   pt.PPointID = newPointID;
   pt.ImportFile = file;
   // assign other properties

   file.Points.Add(pt);
   newPointID +=1;
} while (!eof)

if (fileNew)
    repository.Add(file); 
else
    repository.Update(file); // get an error here
```

I've added Position column to Point table and class and now trying to get collection of points after loading existing record and get old error: 
**failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: PPImportFile.Points**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. Firstly always map collections as **interfaces**: Available types are listed here [6.1. Persistent Collections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-persistent) *(e.g. `IList`, `Iesi.Collections.ISet`)*

Secondly, the **index column**. C# IList could be implemented (and List is good example) as a collection containing one value many times (the same Point could be added more then once). The only information which allows .NET to distinguish items in this list is the index. And that's what NHibernate supports

So if your mapping will be:

```
public virtual IList<PPoint> Points { get; set; }
```

And you want to map it as a `<list>` the table should have columns "ForeignKey" and zero-based "Index" column. That index column will be managed by NHibernate, and filled with the `IList` index values. Read more here [19.5.1. Taxonomy](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-taxonomy)

#### Suggestion:

change the mapping to avoid index column, if you cannot change the database.

The `IList<PPoint>` could be mapped as a `<bag>` which has some performance issues (read the links) but it will work for you.

Use the `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>` and `<set>` mapping. Set will assure, that each value is added into collection only once.

More about the `<list>` here http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list

Comment: Thanks, I am using NHibernate with SQLite 2.0 so I don't have feature of Foreign keys. According examples looks like I have to create a new column 'Position' as I don't have at the moment. After edits I've got an error: "Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1". See my updated question.

Comment: By the foreign key I meant: name of column which references parent/collection owner. So yes, you have to creater new column Position and map key like this `<key column="ImportID"`, which says: when *PPImportFile* class looks for its collection, only these with the same *PPImportFile.ImportId* should be used.